# How to upgrade to a newer version of a package than is available in the repository?

Tags: package-management, apt

While using [an open source genealogy program](http://gramps-project.org/) I encountered an error. I submitted [a bug report](http://www.gramps-project.org/bugs/view.php?id=4476) and the author quickly fixed the problem (Yay for open source!).

Now I want off course to try the latest release (3.2.5) of this program (which includes the bugfix for my problem). Apt-get tells me that the version I have installed (3.2.3-1) is already the newest version.

So what is the best way to upgrade to a newer version of a package then is available in the repositories?

Do I:

- remove the version I have currently installed with the package manager. Download the source of the newest version and compile it myself? Will this give problems when newer versions come out? Will I have to update this program manually in the future whenever newer versions come out?
- Should I do the above, but with a program like [checkinstall](http://www.asic-linux.com.mx/~izto/checkinstall/index.php), and remove the manually compiled version once the version can be installed via the package manager?
- Should I make a request for the package to be [backported](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBackports#How%20to%20request%20new%20packages)? I think my request will make little chance because the rules read:

  > Applications to be backported must have meaningful benefits to the user not attainable via other processes. Specifically: The sole purpose must not be to fix a bug or security vulnerability.

Or is there another way to do this correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this particular case then the GRAMPS website provides a download link for a Ubuntu .deb package of version 3.2.5.

On [this listing page](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gramps/files/Stable/3.2.5/) select [`gramps_3.2.5-1_ubuntu10.deb`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gramps/files/Stable/3.2.5/gramps_3.2.5-1_ubuntu10.deb/download) which should be easily installable by double clicking on the downloaded file.

Comment: I will accept this as the correct answer for this specific case, but the question "what is the best option to choose in general?" remains.

Answer (score 0):

Go for 1st => remove the version I have currently installed with the package manager. Download the source of the newest version and compile it myself?

Will this give problems when newer versions come out? => No.

Will I have to update this program manually in the future whenever newer versions come out? => No

Other option is to request repo managers to update software or you can just wait for them to update.

Comment: Where do I find who the repo manager is for a certain package?

Comment: You can try in #ubuntu-devel on irc or just see the launchpad page of that software. in some cases wiki.ubuntu.com is helpful.

Comment: I will accept this as the correct answer for this specific case, but the question "what is the best option to choose in general?" remains. >> no its not remained.I told you to get source code and compile yourself.

Comment: Will apt be aware of the compiled source? How does it "know" that ive compiled a newer version of a given software that is in my list of installed packages?

Comment: i think apt or synaptic will know about complied sources.