# Upgrade Ghostscript to 9.15 on Ubuntu 14.04LTS

Tags: apt, upgrade, package-management

I need to upgrade `ghostscript` to version 9.15. I'm running 14.04LTS, which has version 9.10. I looked at some previous posts on this site, such as [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18498), but I couldn't find a general answer. I also tried downloading `.deb` package and installing via the software center, or compiling the source code, but both methods failed due to dependencies.

So my question is: how to install Ghostscript 9.15 on Ubuntu 14.04LTS?

Comment: @muru I did, [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/676798/upgrade-to-version-newer-than-repositories). Thanks.

Comment: After some more searching, I found an answer [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/675708/update-ghoscript-on-ubuntu-14-04/675710#675710).